# Automatic appended .xctrunner in my XCUITest bundle id while running on device

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcuitest, bundle-identifier

After updating to Xcode 11.3, my all test cases stopped working because of the unnecessary text **.xctrunner** appended with bundle id.

Example- If I am giving bundle id as **abc.com** then it's showing **abc.com.xctrunner** at run time.

[image]

Comment: do you mean 11.3 / 12 beta 3?

Comment: XCode 11.3 updated my answer.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @kye Did not find the solution and created a wild card provisioning profile to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

XCode 11 changed the format for building xcuitest. To run UI test on device create AppId and Profiles for "$YOUR_TEST_BUNDLE_ID.xctrunner".

Set bundle Id for test target without xctrunner like "$YOUR_TEST_BUNDLE_ID"

Here is my Fastlane match config for iOS and Catalyst.

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.test
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER[sdk=*] = match Development com.test.xctrunner
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER[sdk=macosx*] = match Development com.test.xctrunner catalyst
```

One Annoying Xcode issues is, Signing & Capabilities for UITest target shows status error. Because profiles don't match but no build error and UI test works just fine. Status error is bit hidden but love to resolve it.